# Tabletop.js can't see Google Spreadsheet data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get [tabletop.js](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) working for the first time.  Tabletop.js lets you use Google spreadsheets as the data source for a web page.

When I run my code, which is [here on github](https://github.com/lisawilliams/tabletop-js)

I get the following error:

> GET
>   https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/0AppPPX-L4ABKdExWaVBqWFFuV…/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=Tabletop.callbacks.tt136672522586174055
>   400 (Bad Request) tabletop.js:184

Tabletop.js line 184 reads as follows:

```
  document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
```

The google spreadsheet is public and is right here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AppPPX-L4ABKdExWaVBqWFFuVnFYU0Y1OHUwc0dNb3c#gid=0

Comment: ...[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im betting its an error in your URL.

https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop

specifically where it says:

In Google Docs, then go up to the File menu and pick Publish to the web. Fiddle with whatever you want, then click Start publishing. A URL will appear, something like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE&output=html

Copy that! In theory you're interested in the part between key= and & but you can use the whole thing if you want.

Comment: Oh, I will try using the whole thing and report back if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's progress, because it reports new and improved errors, in this case, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property'1' of null on tabletop.js line 75.  Here's the relevant code:

`/* Be friendly about what you accept */

    if(/key=/.test(this.key)) {

      this.log("You passed a key as a URL! Attempting to parse.");

      this.key = this.key.match("key=(.*?)&")[1];`

Answer (score 2):

I wanted you to know that I got an answer to my question from Jonathan Soma, developer of tabletop.js.  Here's a link to his solution: https://twitter.com/dangerscarf/status/326878697284067329

It turns out that making a spreadsheet public via the 'Share' button is a different thing than 'Publish to the Web' via the File menu in Google Docs/Drive.  You have to do BOTH of these things (make the spreadsheet public AND publish it to the web) for it to work.

Comment: yeah i thought your url was missing the ?pub= but it'd been a while and thought they might have changed that.

Answer (score 0):

I have no proof of this, but having a dash in a Google Spreadsheet key may muck something up on Tabletop's end (edit: or Google's end). None of my keys have ever had a dash, and substituting one of my speadsheets into your code gives a proper response.

I'm looking through Tabletop's code, but for now, it might be worth it to create another Google Spreadsheet and hope it doesn't have a dash in its key.

Comment: Huh!  I'm going to try that out!

Comment: Okay, I've got a new spreadsheet with no dash mark in the key: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiT9esEM1Yc5dEp6MnRtT0cwNUJZOGgxY0FVNnV1RlE#gid=0  

When I use the whole URL I get the "Uncaught TypeError" error on line 75; when I use just the key (which I think is 0AiT9esEM1Yc5dEp6MnRtT0cwNUJZOGgxY0FVNnV1RlE) it goes back to being a 400 error.  Should I be including #gid-0?

Comment: Just tested with adding #gid-0 -- makes no difference.

Comment: Your code works with my example sheet, with key: 0Al0yu3Zxr7ZJdFg5VDItTjExRTJVUWxvUlBFVkxEdGc

Just to cover all bases, you're sure the sheet has been published to the web (under File -> Publish to the web...)?

Comment: Okay...your spreadsheet does in fact work.  My freshly created one: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiT9esEM1Yc5dENCb0U3d2NHV2JZbDNkOW5qREF5V2c#gid=0  does not.  Very strange indeed.  It is public, both to view and edit.

Comment: Hi guys!  I wanted you to know that I got an answer to my question from Jonathan Soma, developer of tabletop.js.  Here's a link to his solution: https://twitter.com/dangerscarf/status/326878697284067329

It turns out that making a spreadsheet public via the 'Share' button is a different thing than 'Publish to the Web' via the File menu in Google Docs/Drive.  You have to do BOTH of these things (make the spreadsheet public AND publish it to the web) for it to work.